# Error - Didn't find class "javax.naming.ldap.LdapName"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, unirest

I'm using unirest to get a camfind result.

The full error log :

```
04-14 18:24:39.574    1880-2300/projectco.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-120
Process: projectco.project, PID: 1880
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/naming/ldap/LdapName;
        at com.mashape.relocation.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.extractCNs(AbstractVerifier.java:277)
        at com.mashape.relocation.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.getCNs(AbstractVerifier.java:265)
        at com.mashape.relocation.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:157)
        at com.mashape.relocation.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:140)
```

[...] more "at"s

```
at bookshotco.bookshot2.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:100)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.naming.ldap.LdapName" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/projectco.project-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

[..]

```
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.ldap.LdapName
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 23 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Few people had this problem and even fewer solved it, most of the times using stuff to do with compatibility of different versions which did not work for me.

The emulator I'm using is up to date (nexus 5 on api 21).

Comment: Well, that class does not exist in [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html). Since this library has apparently not been used on Android, you may be better served finding a library that has.

Comment: The problem is it's a library used by unirest api, is there any way to link some jar file to the project ? and where would I be able to download it ?

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend that you use a library that works on Android. We have many such libraries [for general HTTP](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/65) and for [REST requests specifically](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/85).

Comment: I guess I'll have to do that then, gonna pick retrofit because that's the one I wanted to choose before I changed to unirest.
Thank you good sir !

Comment: DIdn't you ask the same question yesterday? Somebody did. It's deleted now.

Answer (score 5):

I've recently had the same issue and it was only happening in obfuscated code. So keeping the whole org.apache package in Proguard rules solved the issue.

```
# Keep Apache Package, since it cannot find some of the classes and throws Verify Error
-keep class org.apache.** {*;}
```

Comment: Work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by requiring ssl (i.e., "useSSL") when connecting to a remote server and NOT having verifyServerCertificate and trustServerCertificate defined as below, and also not having a server certificate defined properly. The system is trying to use an LDAP authentication process, thus the error.

```
val info = Properties()
info.setProperty("useSSL", "true")
info.setProperty("requireSSL", "true")
info.setProperty("user", user)
info.setProperty("password", password)
info.setProperty("verifyServerCertificate", "false")
info.setProperty("trustServerCertificate", "true")
```

Also, if you define:

```
trustServerCertificate=false
```

then you may need to set the following (unless everything matches up):

```
disableSslHostnameVerification=true
```